# EF Code First - searching for a specific row with a specific property value - performance

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

Suppose I have a performance problem when searching a table for an entry. Let's go to an example:

```
public class A {

[Key]
public int Id {get;set;}

public string xyz {get; set;}

}

public class Context : DbContext {

public DbSet<A> AList {get;set;}

public A FindA(string xyz) {

A output = null;

   if(AList.Local != null) {
     output = AList.Local.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.xyz==xyz);
   }

   return output ?? AList.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.xyz==xyz);

}

}
```

The method FindA looks in the Local collection first and, if there is no match, it goes to the database. I need this approach to avoid duplicate insertion of elements.

The problem of this approach is simple: the search on AList.Local has O(n) complexity and, in my case, AList.Local is often bigger than 100,000 records. It would be great if AList.Local was a Dictionary indexed on xyz property; however, EF Code First IDbSet uses an ObservableCollection with no indexing at all.

One possible solution is to maintain a Dictionary as a mirror for AList.Local. However, this is tricky, since the changes to AList.Local are not easy to track.

Another solution is making the xyz property the primary key and use the AList.Find(xyz) method (I hope it is a O(1) search, even if the entity is in local cache). However, I suspect using a string as a primary key would impact performance on my database and increase the index file size a lot.

Could anyone give me a suggestion on how to overcome this situation?

Comment: Why are changes to `Local` collection not easy to track? It is `ObservableCollection` so you can easily subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event and be informed about all changes.

Comment: Also if you have 100k items in your local graph you are probably in trouble anyway as any EF operations on this (such as adding a single row) will be O(N). IMO you would be far better to not track these entities with EF and instead store a minimal representation (such as just the ID + xyz property) in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about high-performance with Entity Framework, then you need to disable change tracking, and do not use LINQ or LINQ Method syntax. Change tracking is the big trouble maker, and using traditional loops instead of LINQ is *around* 2x faster, but we're talking only shaving off milliseconds for a single lookup operation when preferring traditional loops over LINQ however.